# Complex CSS Transform parent perspective

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to do something like interactive version of this:

[image]

It's not that easy because I want to make it fully responsive, and it should zoom the item on click.

I had 3 ideas for doing this:
1) Every item placed in container transformed separately, and on click it just "reverse" transform, center it, zoom to 80% of window's size. It was almost good, but it wasn't responsive, I couldn't position these items properly because of percentage widths.

Example:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19864640/port/layout.html

2) The container which contains all these items is transformed. This way I can put all items in one div, set percentage width of them, set padding in px. Now it may be responsive.

I also decided to change the perspective to "in front" to make it a bit easier.

Unfortunately this time I have another problem. I can't configure the zooming now. Because of transformed container I can't just use standard centering method.

I tried to make "reverse transform" too, but still cant center it to the screen instead of transformed container.

Example:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19864640/Portfolio/index.html

Here's jsfiddle:
jsfiddle.net/c76qek4z/1/

First two blocks in JS are plugins: first to keep ratio of item, and the second one is for easier transitions: ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

3) It's based on second idea, I wanted to append clicked item to body, and then center it and zoom, but again... this time it won't have any transform animation.

I've been trying to do this for about 20 hours, but still can't do this... 
Do you have any ideas? If something is not clear please ask - that's really important for me.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, or it risks being closed.